# IndexOutOfBoundsException when use MappedByteBuffer

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer, mappedbytebuffer

I am thinking of using MappedByteBuffer to store/load some data to a file. Let's assume I have field A of type long and field B of a string looks like below when serialized:
A(long) | B(string)

Now i want to write and read to it. here is a piece of sample code:

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(dataPath.toString(), "rw");
    MappedByteBuffer mbb = file.getChannel().map(FileChannel.MapMode
            .READ_WRITE, 0, 256);
    long num = 500;
    mbb.putLong(0, num); // (1) first write the long value at beginning
    String str = "Hello World!";
    byte[] input = str.getBytes();
    //then write a string
    mbb.put(input, 8, input.length); // (2) IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

So later I can retrieve long by calling `mbb.getLong(0)`
and `mbb.get(outputArray,8,outputArray.length)`

but now i am failing at place (2). any suggestions?

Comment: instead of `8` you have to put `0` as your byte array starts from zero

Comment: also note: you will not be able to use `outputArray.length` as when you're reading - you don't know how much to allocate

Comment: @IlyaBursov thanks! for your first point... it was because i want the string to be the 2nd field which starts at pos 8. and for 2nd point, could i specify a upper bound of MAX_LEN that i know my string would not be longer than that and read into that buffer?

Comment: second argument to `put` is offset in source array, not in destination buffer

Comment: @IlyaBursov i see. thanks. then what is suggested way to put a byte array(src) to current buffer(dst) at a specified pos? always have to call mbb.position(index) to set it, say at 8?

Comment: either call position or just use put (which changes position as it writes into buffer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
mbb.put(destArray, 0, sourceArray.length)
```

I don't think you want to start writing at an 8 byte offset, otherwise you'd be trying to write 8 bytes over the lenght of the array.

Comment: thanks for the response. but i intend to a keep a structure of {long, string} mapped to the file. namely i always retrieve string at pos 8. did i miss anything?

Comment: say you have an array of length 10, what happens when you try and write 10 bytes (array.length) starting at offset 8?

you only have 2 bytes before you go out of bounds.

Comment: thanks sir. now i get what you mean. you meant to say the offset is for the src byte array(outputArray in your code and input in my case)?

Comment: I updated the answer, the offset is where you start writing to the destination array.

Comment: Also, note that when you say `byte[] input = str.getBytes();` in your example, you are creating array of size 12....so when you start writing at offset 8, you only have 4 bytes before going out of bounds.

Comment: mbb.put(destArray, 0, sourceArray.length) would start write to current buffer starting at index of position, right? so i have to call mbb.position(8) each time whenever i want to read string?  thanks.

Comment: I'm not I understand your question, or what you're trying to do.

Comment: thanks. i understood what you answer means, though:) i misunderstood the function parameter. accepted your answer.